# An error ocurred while starting the kernel (Install tornado)

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to run a code in **Spyder python 3.6**, but I get this error:

> An error ocurred while starting the kernel
>
> C:\Users\Hadi\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py:289: VisibleDeprecationWarning: zmq.eventloop.minitornado is deprecated in pyzmq 14.0 and will be removed.
> Install tornado itself to use zmq with the tornado IOLoop.

from ipykernel.kernelapp import IPKernelApp

I have tried these:

- `conda update setuptools`
- `tools -> Reset Spyder to Factory Defaults`

But none of them helped. How can I install tornado to solve this error?

Comment: Please run `conda update pyzmq tornado zmq jupyter_client` and try again.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda and the error went away. Haven't tried your method yet.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba it gives an error `PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35
  package name: zmq   `